# How do I break out of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, break

If I have something like this:

```
var x = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    if (x == "1") {x = "2"};
    if (x == "2") {x = "3"};
    if (x == "3") {x = "1"};
}, 250);
```

At the moment, the function runs the first `if` since it is inherintly true, then since the first `if` alters `x` to meet the conditions of the second `if`, it runs that as well, then does the same with the third and sets `x` all the way back to `1` How do I get each of the `if` functions to break out of the `setInterval` funtion so that after it has ran, the other `if`s will not run? 
I've found how to do this with loops but not for functions. I understand that the above function would probably be better suited in a loop, but it's only an example for the sake of keeping the question short.

Comment: `return`? Use `else if`s?

Comment: Either make them if->else if->else if, or add a return statement to each if block.

Comment: For some reason Else If gives me a console error. I'll try return though.

Comment: @AustinGriner What's that error?

Comment: Or use `x = {"1": "2", "2": "3", "3": "1"}[x];`.

Comment: @AustinGriner You also need to remove the unnecessary semicolons after the `if` bodies.

Comment: Oh I'm dumb I swear sorry I just had to remove the semicolons for else if...

Comment: @Xufox is there a term for that notation?

Comment: Looks more like a job for `switch case` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ternary expression for this simple case:

```js
var x = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  x < 3 ? x++ : x=1
  console.log(x)
}, 250);

// clears the interval after 5000 ms
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 5000);
```